# Не парсится сайт

Tags: python, парсер

Начал изучать парсинг. Хочу получить данные сайта, но выдаёт None. До этого пробовал на другом сайте, доже None было. (Были сайты, которые парсились нормально)

```py
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {
    'user-Agent': ua.random,
}


def parser(url):
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

        main_div = soup.find('main', attrs={'class': 'layout__content'})
        print(main_div)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.mvideo.ru/products/videokarta-gigabyte-geforce-rtx3080-ti-gaming-oc-12g-30057779'
    parser(url)
```

Comment: многие популярные сайты активно (а иногда и агресивно) сопротивляются парсингу. В каждом конкретном случае люди ищут свои подходы. Но в общем, есть один подход - не нужно парсить все моментально - Вас адрес гарантировано попадет в бан лист. Парсить нужно очень потихоньку.

Comment: Как это - потихоньку?

Comment: один запрос в 10-20 минут.

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду, что запросы это типо soup.find() или что?

Comment: Find это не запрос. Это работа с скачанными данными.  Запрос это get, но **Вы**можете наставить sleep везде, хуже не будет

Comment: Спасибо большое)